# How to programmatically close TimePickerAndroid

Tags: javascript, react-native

There is function `TimePickerAndroid.open()` that starts TimePickerAndroid, but I can't find anywhere one that closes it. I need to be able to close it other way than simply clicking on "Cancel" or "Ok". Or maybe is it possible to run "Cancel" with separate function?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that TimePickerAndroid doesn't have a programmatic "hide" support and apart from pulling a request there is not much to do in this matter.

So I was forced to create my own Time Picker for React Native. Feel free to use it -> https://github.com/vasyl91/React-Native-Wheel-Time-Picker